# How do I display selected values using Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I am using [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin for developing a drop-down which includes check boxes.

The values gets sent properly into my DB while submitting. But, while retrieving the same selected data, I can't seem to display multiple values.

When there is just one selected values, it gets displayed perfectly using `.val()` but when multiple values are present the `.val()` fails to display anything.

So, I tried searching the [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/) site and found `.multiselect('select',values)` method.

Now, the multiple values are getting displayed but there are two dropdowns now.

Maybe because I am calling `.multiselect` twice. Please help me in displaying multiple values and a single dropdown. Here's my code:

```
<select id="Damage_@item.Id" name="Damage_@item.Id" class="form-control multiselect" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="0" selected>Pick One</option>
<input type="hidden" id="Hidden_Damage_@item.Id" name="Hidden_Damage_@item.Id" value="@item.Damage" />
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$(function () {
                $('.multiselect').multiselect({
                    onInitialized: function (select, container) {


                        var selectedDamageValues = $('#Hidden_' + select[0].id).val();
                        console.log(selectedDamageValues);
                        var array = selectedDamageValues.split(",");



                },
        numberDisplayed: 1,
            buttonWidth: '100%'
            });
        //});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: add html of drop down you used

Comment: added drop down code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `$(selector).multiselect('select', [array of values]);` to assign select item programticly

see below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
      if (options.length == 0) {
          return 'Select Groups';
      }
      else {
          var selected = '';
          options.each(function() {
              selected += $(this).text() + ', ';
          });
          return selected.substr(0, selected.length -2);
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('#example-getting-started').multiselect('select', ['one', 'four']);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
```